# Prisma 2 query relation return null

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, prisma-graphql, prisma2

I migrated my project  from prisma 1.
Then I added new models relative to my Live model.
I try to query the new models with relation type (one-to-one and one-to-many) but that returns null.

Here is my prisma.schema

[image]

Query live.questionnaire{} works but questionnaire.live{} doesn't, and both questionnaire.questionnaireField{} and questionnaireField.questionnaire{} dont't wortk.

Here is an exemple of the playground

live.questionnaire is ok.
[image]

questionnaire.live is not.
[image]

My schemas

Live schema perview where relation live.questionnaire ok
[image]

Each of questionnaire.live and questionnaire.fields and questionnaireField.questionnaire are down
[image]
[image]

My query resolver where only createdAt works

[image]
In prisma studio everything seems to be good...

If someone could help, Thanks

Comment: Can you add a live model preview in your schema screenshot?
Also, the two screenshots from the playground see the same thing

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have updated the playground screenshots and the live model preview is just below the playgrounds

Comment: There is no issue in your codes.
Try to get a questionnaire.live by the same id in the first playground query.
Also, try to use your code on a new empty DB maybe you have an issue in your first DB from upgrading from Prisma 1 to Prisma 2

If you can replicate your issue in a GitHub repo with a simple code, not all your project will be very helpful to find the issue with you

Answer (score 0):

See your resolvers not clear but I will give you a way to build your GraphQL server with Prisma in just minute using [Pal.Js CLI](http://paljs.com/) you can start new project with my CLI and just put your schema and run one command `pal g` and you will get everything ready for you with full CRUD system.

Install my CLI

```sh
yarn global add @paljs/cli
//or
npm install -g @paljs/cli
```

Start new project

```sh
> pal c


.______      ___       __             __       _______.
|   _  \    /   \     |  |           |  |     /       |
|  |_)  |  /  ^  \    |  |           |  |    |   (----`
|   ___/  /  /_\  \   |  |     .--.  |  |     \   \
|  |     /  _____  \  |  `----.|  `--'  | .----)   |
| _|    /__/     \__\ |_______| \______/  |_______/

✔ Please select your start example · apollo-sdl-first
  full-stack-nextjs
  full-stack-gatsbyjs
  apollo-nexus-schema
❯ apollo-sdl-first // select this example
  graphql-modules

✔ please enter your project name · great-project
✔ please enter your project description · new NodeJs Prisma GraphQL TypeScript project
✔ please enter your project author · Ahmed Elywa
✔ please enter your project repository · https://github.com/paljs/prisma-tools
✔ please select your package manager · yarn
❯ yarn
  npm

✔ Skip package installation · no
❯ yes
  no
```

Now open your project folder and change `./prisam/schema.prisma` file with yours

now generate all resolvers

```sh
pal g
```

you have now your graphql server ready

start your server

```sh
yarn dev
or
npm run dev
```

that is it

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the project is already in production, and 20 others models work fine, the problem happens when I want to add the questionnaire and other s new models relative to the live model...

Comment: Yes, and what I say to you that you can make an example project with my setup and if you don't get the issue with my setup so you can compare and know where is the issue.